# Jquery accordion - load first active panel via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, accordion

I'm doing a jQuery accordion via:

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#gallery-preview").accordion({ header: "h2",          
                animate: 400,
                heightStyle: "content",
                active: 1,
                alwaysOpen: false,
                fillspace: false,
                collapsible: true,
                activate: function (e, ui) {
                $url = $(ui.newHeader[0]).children('a').attr('href');
                $.get($url, function (data) {
                    $(ui.newHeader[0]).next().html(data);
                });
            }

        });
    });
```

that loads the content via Ajax.

But I have two problems:

1) The active accordion does not load the content until the accordion is closed and opened again. Is there a way to load the content for the initially first (active) accordion?

2) How do I prevent that accordion tabs that had already been load via Ajax are not loaded again after closing and reopening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the problem, but I'll try to help you out. I think the main issue you're seeing is that you're running the AJAX and other stuff inside of the activate, which is ran every time the accordion is activated but NOT run on the initial creation. Try swapping out 'activate' for 'create' and see if that works. If I understand your questions correctly, that should both make it load on creation rather than after close/open and that should stop the tab content from reloading each time since create is only fired on creation. See the note in yellow under the activate section here:

https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By simply swapping 'activate' to 'create' the accordion stops it's functionality. But you do understand what I try to achieve :)

Comment: are you getting any errors? I'd recreate it on fiddle or something but it would be difficult without the ajax call and all of your elements and such.